# How to mimic appending to Python dictionary values in VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to mimic in VBA a Python script I have written that creates dicitonary dynamically. I am running into problems on the last line of the following loop:

```
Dim transactions As New Scripting.dictionary
Dim used_parents As collection
Set used_parents = New collection
Dim parent_count As Integer
Dim groups As New Scripting.dictionary

[...]

For Each Key In transactions.Keys
    used_parents.Add transactions(Key)
    parent_count = col_item_count(transactions(Key), used_parents)
    groups(parent_count).Add Key' this does not work; I need to somehow tell VBA that "groups(parent_count)" is a collection, to be able to add to that collection
Next Key
```

I need the `groups(parent_count)` dictionary value to be a collection in order to append to it.

Is it possible in VBA to have collection as dictionary value?

For reference, working Python code looks like this (keys in dictionary are lists, so I can easily append to them):

```
from collections import defaultdict

partials = ['tomek','jacek','agata','piotrek','stefan','kasia','krystyna','janek','pawel','leopold']
parents = ['a','b','c','d','a','d','f','c','c','a']
transactions = zip(partials, parents)

used_parents = []
groups = defaultdict(List)

for key, value in transactions:
    used_parents.append (value)
    parent_count = used_parents.Count(value)
    groups ['Group ' + str(parent_count)].append(key)
```

Comment: Yes, you can store objects in a Collection or a Dictionary. When adding to the Collection you can optionally tag the entry with a key.

Comment: Can you use a counter variable in the loop and and do  groups(parent_count)(counter) =  Key ?

Comment: Yesyou can store collections in dictionaries. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444816/vba-can-i-put-a-collection-inside-a-scripting-dictionary